# HTTP and HTTPS Protocols

Tags: security, http, authentication, https, protocols

my question is related to hypertext protocol.

what is the requirements from my side to be able to use HTTPS instead of HTTP in the areas where a user will enter confident information or when there is a registration process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a certificate (you can [buy one](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssl+certificates), which are usually identified by browsers, or create a [self-signed certificate](http://sial.org/howto/openssl/self-signed/), which will trigger a warning on browsers) and a server able to run HTTPS. HTTPS capable servers allow you to define which pages are served via HTTP and which via HTTPS.

HTTPS IS NOT authentication, by the way, it only encrypts communications to prevent eavesdroppers reading what's being sent between the server and client.

You can use any authentication method over HTTPS, but you need to provide it (be it HTTP Auth or something in your application.)

There isn't much more to say given your ambiguous question.

Answer (score 2):

Primarily, you need to configure your webserver to use https; this in turn requires that you have a server certificate. You can either create your own server certificate, or you can buy one from one of the Certificate Authorities. The latter will cause browsers to trust that your site is genuine (whereas in the case of one that you created yourself, a man-in-the-middle or phishing attack might happen from the viewpoint of the browser).

How to configure your server precisely should be discussed on serverfault.